# Does Jpa Entity get persisted anywhere if i do not do .save() (Springboot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, entity, javabeans

this has been on my mind for a couple of days now, so I've decided to post a question here. The question is more general but the answer will greatly change my coding logic.

The question is this: Let's say I have @Entity class Person with some random values. if I create a new one in my service or even in some other repo with a custom query like this

> @Query("SELECT new package.Person FROM Department d WHERE ....")

After that, if I do not use the actual save method of its origin repository, but rather I use it as a temporary DTO. Will that Person entity get persisted/cached somewhere for later DB use via JPA or will it be treated like a regular java bean?

Thanks for taking your time to read this topic.

Comment: Possibly. As long as your entity resides in a transactional context, it might happen that your object is written back to the database, although you never called any of the persisting methods of the entityManager. Think of Spring Proxies that are created when annotating methods with ``@Transactional``.